# Balance in continuously compounded interest

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> $3000$ dollar is deposited into a saving account at $5$% interest compounded continuously.How fast the ballance growing when it reach $7000$(means finding rate of growth of  investment per year)

What i try

For continuously compounded interest

$P=P_{0}e^{rt}$, where $P_{0}=3000,r=5$%

Then equation is $P=3000e^{0.05t}$

Then $$7000=3000\times 0.05e^{0.05t}$$

$$e^{0.05t}=\frac{7}{3}\Longrightarrow 0.05 t=\ln(7/3)$$

So we get $$t=2\ln(7/3)$$

Is my process is right.

If it not, Then Help me  to explain me right process please

Comment: Your work is fine except you have a stray $0.05$ in the line $7000=3000...$ and  dropped a $0$ in the last line as $\frac 1{0.05}=20$.  You did not answer the question of how fast the balance is growing.  For that you should find $\frac {dP}{dt}$ and evaluate it at the (corrected) $t$ from the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(t)=f(0)e^{rt}$ be the amount in the saving account at time $t$. If $f(0)=3,000$ and $r=0.05$, then $$f(t)=3000e^{0.05t}$$

Observe $f'(t)$ is the rate of change of the amount in the savings account at time $t$, so when $f(t)=7000$, your calculation shows: $$7000=3000e^{0.05t}\implies\ln\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)=0.05t\implies t=20\ln\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)$$

Thus the rate of change of the balance in the account when there is $7,000$  in the bank, or at time $t=20\ln\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)$, is denoted $f'\left(20\ln\left(\frac{7}{3}\right)\right)$.